# Mobile Graph/Chart SDK or Library for IONIC IN ANGULAR 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am looking for a Mobile Graph/Chart SDK or Library for  Ionic in Angular 4 and HTML.

I found some libraries like Chart.js and Google Charts etc. but puzzled which one is better for mobile.

Can anyone suggest me which one is better to use in my mobile application?

Comment: I am using chart.js very simple to use and quick to implement and work smooth with android and ios

Comment: @PareshGami Thanks.